# Catalyst Plugin Session deleting session before it is used

Tags: perl, session, catalyst, dbix-class

I'm using [Catalyst::Plugin::Session](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session) along with [Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::DBIC](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::DBIC) and [CatalystX::SimpleLogin](https://metacpan.org/pod/CatalystX::SimpleLogin). I've used these multiple times before, but I'm getting some strange behavior currently. What I'm seeing is that once I login the session is created, then deleted, and then there is an attempt to update the session row that doesn't exist and this causes a crash. Here are the queries that are being run:

```
INSERT INTO sessions ( id) VALUES ( ? ): 'session:ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573'

DELETE FROM sessions WHERE ( id = ? ): 'session:ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573'

DELETE FROM sessions WHERE ( id = ? ): 'flash:ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573'

UPDATE sessions SET expires = ?, session_data = ? WHERE ( id = ? ): '1467954773', 'BQoDAAAABQp5TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKE1hY2ludG9zaDsgSW50ZWwgTWFjIE9TIFggMTBfMTFfNCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzUxLjAuMjcwNC4xMDMgU2FmYXJpLzUzNy4zNgAAAAxfX3VzZXJfYWdlbnQJV33k1QAAAAlfX2NyZWF0ZWQJV33k1QAAAAlfX3VwZGF0ZWQKBXVzZXJzAAAADF9fdXNlcl9yZWFsbQQDAAAAAQiBAAAAAmlkAAAABl9fdXNlcg==', 'session:ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573'
```

Here is the debug output I'm seeing:

```
[debug] Created session "ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573"

[debug] Created session "aec058e68a823f5711d64b18ad8c53611b1b832f"

[debug] change_sessid: deleting session data from "ff4732c1779d955a73d31b967db50ba59d3c0573"

[debug] change_sessid: storing session data to "aec058e68a823f5711d64b18ad8c53611b1b832f"
```

And here is the crash:

http://pastebin.com/nWA0X6Lb

I checked and the function that is calling `delete_session_data` is `Catalyst::Plugin::Session::change_session_id`.

Also, this works when I use [Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::File](https://metacpan.org/pod/Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::File) instead of Catalyst::Plugin::Session::Store::DBIC.

Does anyone know what could be going wrong?

**UPDATE:**

I checked on one of my other servers that works, and it looks like for some reason the delete queries aren't there:

```
INSERT INTO sessions ( id) VALUES ( ? ): 'session:08844c28572b99acd3603d50c2c3975d13c3a4b8'

UPDATE sessions SET expires = ?, session_data = ? WHERE ( id = ? ): '1467956394', 'BQcDAAAABgp5TW96aWxsYS81LjAgKE1hY2ludG9zaDsgSW50ZWwgTWFjIE9TIFggMTBfMTFfNCkgQXBwbGVXZWJLaXQvNTM3LjM2IChLSFRNTCwgbGlrZSBHZWNrbykgQ2hyb21lLzUxLjAuMjcwNC4xMDMgU2FmYXJpLzUzNy4zNgAAAAxfX3VzZXJfYWdlbnQKBXVzZXJzAAAADF9fdXNlcl9yZWFsbQoONTAuMTc0LjI0Mi4yNTMAAAAJX19hZGRyZXNzBAMAAAABCgExAAAAAmlkAAAABl9fdXNlcgoKMTQ2Nzg2OTk5NAAAAAlfX2NyZWF0ZWQKCjE0Njc4Njk5OTQAAAAJX191cGRhdGVk', 'session:08844c28572b99acd3603d50c2c3975d13c3a4b8'
```

**Further update:**

I'm using perl 5.24. I thought that might be relevant. I'm going to try downloading an older perl version and seeing if that works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I believe I found the issue. I think a bug was introduced in [v 0.19](https://metacpan.org/release/ABRAXXA/CatalystX-SimpleLogin-0.19). The fix I found was commenting out this line in the Login Controller:

```
if( $form->process(ctx => $ctx, params => $p) ) { 
    #$ctx->change_session_id;

    $self->remember_me($ctx, $form->field( 'remember' )->value);

    $self->do_post_login_redirect($ctx);
}
```

For now I'm just going to downgrade to version 0.18.